# Multiple JTextFields?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, layout-manager

I'm confused if you can have more than 1 JtextField inside of a single JPanel? If yes, then how with the code provided below.

my code:

```
private JPanel jp;
private JTextField jt;

jt = new JTextField();
jt.setBounds(1, 25, 60, 20);
jp.add(jt);
jt.setColumns(10);

JLabel npcId = new JLabel("npcId");
npcId.setBounds(15, 11, 92, 14);
jp.add(npcId);
```

What I'm building:

[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish here is have 5 `JTextField` objects: npcId, npcLocation, npcReg, npcAH, npcAA.

Comment: Of course you can. What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation related to Swing Layout Manager http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html
It is very flexible way to control position of GUI elements

Comment: `Don't use setBounds().` Where ever you found that example get rid of it. You should be using layout managers as suggested above.

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: I was going off what I read in a java doc like a year ago & I couldn't find the book I saw it in, lost it in my house somewhere. But @ john I've tried copying npcId & changing it... failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's very easy, you need to make use of an appropriate layout manager.

Take a look,at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

I might suggest starting with something GridLayout, but eventually, you'll want to look at GridBagLayout.

Don't forget, you can use compound layouts to create sophisticated layouts

Answer (score 1):

Also, you might consider those basic methods:

```
// Use of Textfield
usernameField = new JTextField(8);
usernameField.setLocation(0, 0);
usernameField.setSize(100, 30);
```

Comment: So `jt = new JTextField();
jt.setLocation(0,0);
jt.setSize(100, 30);`

how would I go about duplicating that to make more text fields....?

Comment: for example `jt2 = new JTextField();` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can it easily, what you realy have to is
1) declare all your JTextFields like :

```
jt = new JTextField();
jt.setBounds(1, 25, 60, 20);
jp.add(jt);
jt.setColumns(10);
```

2) declare your JPanel like

```
private JPanel jp;

jp = new JPanel();// here you have to set a layout manager for this panel
//for exampl:
jp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

check the Layout Managers from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

3) add all declared JTextFields to your panel :

```
jp.add(jt);
jp.setVisible(true);
```